# Getting the (parent) process executing the command in Linux shell

Tags: linux, process, ps

Please advice , how to verify the program that execute the process ?

For example

the following commands ( ps -ef ) will view the process sendmail in case this process is running

```
  ps –ef | grep sendmail
  root     9558 9544 019:05?      00:00:00/usr/sbin/sendmail-FCronDaemon-i-odi-oem-oi-t
```

what I want to find is the script that execute the binary  **/usr/sbin/sendmail**

so my question – which flags I need to add to the syntax "ps –ef"  in order to get from ps –ef the full details , include which program running the process

is it possible ?

- Example and remark

If
**/etc/rc3.d/sendmail** run the binary **/usr/sbin/sendmail**

Then I expect to see the **/etc/rc3.d/sendmail** PATH from the command ps –ef …….

Comment: you can use `pstree -Aap` to generate a tree list of all the running processes in the system, but don't think you can get your expected result

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What do you need is a tree output and know the parent processes.

Example `pstree -a`:

```
[~]# pstree -a
init
  ├─atd
  ├─atop -a -w /var/log/atop.log 600
  ├─cron
  ├─dbus-daemon --system --fork --activation=upstart
  ├─getty -8 38400 tty4
  │   ├─sshd
  │   └─sshd
  │       └─zsh
  │           └─pstree -a
  ├─udevd --daemon
  │   ├─udevd --daemon
  │   └─udevd --daemon
  ├─upstart-socket- --daemon
  ├─upstart-udev-br --daemon
```

Here you can see that there is a process of `zsh` (my shell) which is running command `pstree`. The `zsh` itself was started by process `sshd`.

Here is the same output for `ps -AF`:

```
root     10006   649  0 22329  3944   0 12:48 ?        00:00:00 sshd: root@pts/2
root     10041 10006  0 10355  5276   0 12:48 pts/2    00:00:00 -zsh
root     16465 10041  0  4538  1220   0 12:52 pts/2    00:00:00 ps -AF
```

The second column is process id and the third column is **parent process id**. You see that the parent of `ps -AF` is the shell process `10041`. You can always trace back processes to the init (process id 1) by walking them parent by parent.

In your case if you want to find `/etc/rc3.d/sendmail` you probably need to walk processes up from `/usr/sbin/sendmail` until you have something of which full path us under `/etc/rc3.d`.